# Accessing array- which is faster - "pointer reference" or just accessing the array "variable (index)"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Suppose I need to read a binary file (500 Megabytes), so, I would just load that file by reading it into a bit array. After that, I want to read it one by one (one bit by bit). So, I can just read the "variable" (by index) of the array or read the value by the "pointer" (provided that I know the pointer address of the first element of the array). So, which will be fastest in this scenario?

do you have any other suggestions to load a file to read bits, other than loading it into a bitarray or any other array for better performance?

Comment: This is so broad I don't even know what follow up questions to ask. Let me give it a try: what kind of file? What does it contain? Why do you need to read bit by bit? What do you mean "read the variable by index"? Have you actually tested that this is a bottle neck? What "bitarray" do you mean? `std::bitset`? How do pointers related to this bit-by-bit reading, given that pointers refer to bytes?

Comment: Remember that arrays decays to pointers, and that for any pointer *or* array `a`, `a[x]` is equivalent to `*(a + x)`. And the compiler will probably generate the same code for both expressions.

Comment: `I want to read it one bit by bit` -> didn't you mean *byte*, perhaps? Why would you want to process *500 MB* by single bit at time? This would be performance killer anyway.

Comment: There is only one answer to this question. Try the different techniques and time them. What is faster for you might not be faster for someone else. There are too many variables to say that one technique is definitely better than another.

Comment: @ ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ : may it be any kind of file, but not a text file, I have already mentioned that this file is a binary file, so, it just contains 500 MB of 01011001 like data  :) so, don't worry about that part, suppose the array is full of 1010010 data (index 0 will contain 1, index 1 will contain 0 etc), and begin thinking from there ;) .... Further, I need to read it one by one, because, I will use conditional operators after that, for example, if first 5 bits (0-4) are "10011" then write "patern1", if second set (5-9) are "01111" then write "patern2" etc. :)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Yeah, I have a doubt about that too, I use VS2012 so, the compiler might be generating the same machine code as the new compilers are smarter in code optimizing, than ages old compilers.  But theoretically, is the pointer fast than accessing array, when we know the pointer address of the first element of the array, cos, we just have to increase the pointer address by 1 to access the next element.

Comment: @ Mateusz Grzejek: Yes, this is a performance killer :) that's why I search for better ways to handle those data as for my program it's necessary to access the file bit by bit (actually about 5 bits at a time) (not byte) which will be then used to find patterns. :) you just think that the array has been already filled by 0101011 like data (bits) so, I just need to read those things from memory or from register a bit faster. it will save about few minutes when I read the whole file from begin to end bit by bit.

Comment: @john: yes, I'm gonna try it next ... :)

Comment: The two expressions in my previous comment are equivalent because they do the exact same thing: Add an offset to a base address. How else do you think that array indexing works? The compiler knows the base address of the array, the size of the type used in the array, and the index, so what it does is basically `arrayBaseAddress + (sizeof(arrayType) * index)` to get to the memory where the value at index `index` is stored.

Answer (score 1):

They are literally the same thing, and it has nothing to do with "optimisation".

For a standard array `myArray`, the following:

```
myArray[2]
```

is *defined* to be equivalent to:

```
*(&myArray[0] + 2)
```

and (thanks to array name decay):

```
*(myArray + 2)
```

So, neither will be "faster". In both cases, your compiler will generate the fastest code it can to represent your program semantics.

In general, *measure* for performance differences before deciding to care about minutiae like this.